# "object is not iterable" error on my python implementation of iterable

Tags: python, iterable

I am trying to create a iterable class but have been banging my head on a wall so to speak, getting "object is not iterable". This is my code:

```py
class myiterable:
    def __init__(self, somelist):
        self.i = 0
        self.l = somelist

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.i < len(self.l):
            self.i = self.i + 1
            return self.l[self.i-1]
        else:
            raise StopIteration



for i in myiterable([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]):
    print(i)
```

What's wrong? I have also tried `next(self)` in lieu of `__next__(self)` to no avail!

Comment: Look at your indentation. See anything wrong here? Please do correct it if this is not what you meant. If you don't see anything wrong, look harder and that's your problem.

Comment: `++self.i` is **not** python syntax, btw. Use `self.i += 1`. Your version will just lead to an infinite loop instead.

Comment: Fixed code and posted new version. Same problem.

Comment: If this is the fixed version then you just found your problem. `__iter__` and `__next__` are not methods on `myiterable`; they are nested functions inside `__init__`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for pointing out my other mistakes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just copied your code, then it should be because of bad indent. Pull `__iter__` and `__next__` to same indent as `__init__`.

Comment: My God! I cannot believe I fell for such a stupid mistake! Thanks man!

Answer (score 5):

There are several problems with your code:

- indentation
- if you are on python 2, you should have defined [next()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.next) method instead of `__next__()` (leave it as is if on python 3)
- `++self.i` should be replaced with `self.i += 1`
- `self.l[i-1]` should be replaced with `self.l[self.i-1]`

---

```
class myiterable:
    def __init__(self, somelist):
        self.i = 0
        self.l = somelist

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        if self.i < len(self.l):
            self.i += 1
            return self.l[self.i-1]
        else:
            raise StopIteration


for i in myiterable([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]):
    print(i)
```

prints:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: Python 3 uses `.__next__()`, **not** `.next()`.

Comment: The OP uses `print(i)`, you can assume Python 3 here.